# Why `fail` inside `catch(Exception ex)` handling `assertEquals` is not called?

Tags: java, junit

I had the question some minutes before but I want to try something else..

For Example I have this method:

```
//inside Number.java
public static int add(int nr1, int nr2) {
    return nr2 + nr2;
}
```

As you see I return number2 + number2

In my Test I use that it would throw the error that it was expected 9 instead of the number which was calculate in the main method.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    int nr1 = 4;
    int nr2 = 5;
    int sum = Number.add(nr1, nr2);
    assertEquals(9, sum);
}
```

I tried this now to get an message if the program fails but it doesn´t with fail..

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    int nr1 = 4;
    int nr2 = 5;
    int sum = Number.add(nr1, nr2);
    
    try {
        assertEquals(9, sum);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        fail("Are you sure you calculate the right numbers?");
    }
}
```

But the program is only showing me the AssertionError not the Message in fail()

I know now that I can use it this way:

```
assertEquals("...",9,sum);
```

but I don't want this AssertionError:

```
expected:<> but was <>
```

at the end

Comment: First - you have the same assertion prior to the try-catch block so you have no chance of catching it.  Second - consider catching Throwable if you want to catch the assertion failure.  Third - why do you want less information from your test failure output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `AssertionError` extends `Error` which implements `Throwable`. Your

```
catch(Exception e)
```

is useless because the `AssertionError` is not an `Exception`.

Catch it directly using `catch(AssertionError e)` if you must, but usually `Error`s are not supposed to be caught.

If you really want to force a call to `fail`, avoid the `assertEquals` and just use

```
if(sum != 9) {
  fail("Are you sure you calculate the right numbers?");
}
```

which avoids the AssertionError altogether.

Comment: BTW in second `test()` example OP has `assertEquals(9, sum);` *twice*. First one is outside of try-catch so when it fails flow of control would be moved outside of method. This would prevent second `assertEquals(9, sum);` from executing.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks :) but in real I delete it ..